# Copy Bone Rotation Constraints Between Armatures with Different Initial Bone Angles

Tags: animation, bone.constraints

i have three horse rigs that are all built slightly differently.  i want to create one master rig to animate them all :X

[image: left: Rig1 center: Master Rig right: Rig2]

left: Rig1  center: Master Rig  right: Rig2

the problem is, no matter which space to which space i choose, something screws up.

it seems a no-brainer that 'pose space' to 'pose space' means 'if the master bone is set to 0 rotation, then set the constrained bone to 0 rotation.'
however, the constrained bones point straight down, NOT at their zero rotation (which is at an angle in their respective rigs.)

the pose actually LOOKS okay, from the side, but it is not.   Rig1, for example, has the thigh bone angled out, while the master rig has it straight up and down.

[image: Rig1 on the left has its knee crunching into its torso.]

you can see in this pose, that Rig1 on the left has its knee crunching into its torso.

i can fix this by changing to local space.  UNLESS i then want to rotate the rig by the pelvis.

[image: this is the same pose as above, but with the hip rotated]

this is the same pose as above, but with the hip rotated.  (Rig2, right, is still using pose space to pose space, so at least it doesn't start pointing an entirely different direction.)

yes, the screenshots are in blender 279, but i opened this file in 360, and none of the options in those constraints gave me any different (usable) results.

HOW can i tell these bones to just.... copy the rotation of the bone i point them to?  is this going to involve scripts and stuff??  i'll need to keyframe everything, too.  shouldn't the bone constraint be able to handle this type of situation?

HELP!

IN ADDITION.... (yes, i want the world).  some of the bones axes don't match.  i got my horizontal hip control to map to the vertical controls on these rigs.  but Rig1, for example, the hoof bone there is 'backwards' compared to the master rig.  i tried using invert on an/all X/Y/Z axes, but no combination thereof, nor offset (with Y at 180) was able to un-twist it.

in this particular instance, i think i might have to add a 'mediator' bone to Rig1, that will read the Master bone constraint, and then the Rig1 bone will be constrained to that in a different manner that will face it right way 'round.

...but i can't do that with every single bone in all the rigs :/  (in a timely manner!)

i can't possibly be the first person who's wanted to do something like this??  it SHOULD be workable... i hope!?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correctly insert your images to your post so that we can see them. You can copy your image where you posted them, then paste them here : they should be automatically uploaded and inserted as they should be.

Comment: oh, apologies.  i didn't notice the image button.
however, it isn't accepting the lightshot urls.  and neither is imagur.  i will look for an alternate solution.

Comment: It will be probably best to upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to add the link, so that we can check the whole rig and see how it works. Also, have you considered that instead of trying to make different rigs match each other, it would be simpler to just animate one rig, then copy the animation to the others and do the little adaptations they might need? That's how we retarget animations usually. I doubt the rig system you are wishing for will make it so you don't need to adjust the animations for each rigs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is the bone copying the rotation of its target but ignoring the rotation inherited from the target's parent, use Local Space:

[image]

If you want to copy the rotation with the parent's inherited rotation but ignore the armature object's rotation, use Pose Space:

[image]

If you want the above but that also takes the armature object's rotation, use World Space:

[image]

Comment: these are good explanations and examples.
...
yet, in image 1, i'm using pose space to pose space.  and when the master bone is at zero rotation, the constrained bones are at some rotation to match the world angle of that bone.
...
and in image 3, if i use local space, rotating the master root bone (which rotates the constrained root bones) causes the child bone to point in a totally different direction.

Comment: what do i use, both 'from' and 'to',  to get every bone in the constrained rigs to match the actual rotation of its corresponding bone in the master rig? not the 'where it looks like it is pointing' (straight down in image one), but where it is actually rotated (zero rotation).